# How to fix the issue: In jar creation with mongo DB dependencies for stand alone progam

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, executable-jar

I have generated the executable fat jar file in java with the following dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.function.thumbnail</groupId>
    <artifactId>Thumbnail</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Thumbnail</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Amazon s3 bucket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <finalName>dateutils</finalName>
        <plugins>
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.function.thumbnail.ThumbnailGenarationStandAloneFunctionality</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried mvn install command in command-prompt jar generated successfully after that I have tried to run jar at that time the above issues raised.

```
 Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

can you please suggest  How to Create the Executable JAR file with resources and dependencies using Maven in Eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: I have tried this one too jar generated successfully but when am running the  jar at that time the above issue raised `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException
`

Comment: May be jar is generated successfully without dependencies. Check the jar to see if it contains mongodb dependency.

Comment: I have added all dependencies in `pom.xml` file

Comment: Sorry I don't have the setup to test this for you but you need to update plugin config to include assembly plugin as suggested in the linked duplicate to include the dependencies in your jar.

Comment: **thank you** as u suggested I have used following dependency it's working fine `<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>`